# Pdf timestamped signature: timestamp authority not available

Tags: java, pdf, timestamp, itext

I'm using iText 2.1.7 and BC 1.49
Even though I can signing and timestamping a file, when I open it with adobe reader I get a "timestamp authority not available" status (signature it's ok and reader tell me that the file is timestamped).
Here is my code after when timestamping:

```
...
byte[] tstoken = timeStampClient.getTimeStampToken(tsdata);
Attribute signatureTimeStamp = new Attribute(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_aa_signatureTimeStampToken, new DERSet(ASN1Primitive.fromByteArray(tstoken)));
SignerInformationStore signerStore = cmsSignedData.getSignerInfos();
ArrayList<SignerInformation> siArray = new ArrayList<SignerInformation>();
Iterator<SignerInformation> infos = signerStore.getSigners().iterator();
while (infos.hasNext()) {
    SignerInformation si = infos.next();
    Hashtable<ASN1ObjectIdentifier, Attribute> unsignedAttrHash = si.getUnsignedAttributes().toHashtable();
    unsignedAttrHash.put(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_aa_signatureTimeStampToken, signatureTimeStamp);
    siArray.add(SignerInformation.replaceUnsignedAttributes(si, new AttributeTable(unsignedAttrHash)));
}
SignerInformationStore newSignerStore = new SignerInformationStore(siArray);
return CMSSignedData.replaceSigners(cmsSignedData, newSignerStore);
...
```

The returned CmsSignedData (.getEncoded()) is what I embbed into pdf. I already test the TSA server and signer certificate using Acrobat and those are ok.

Thank you in advance.

-- Added --
Examples:

[My signed pdf](http://ubuntuone.com/0loVGotp2la3u9mg6oMD8O)

[Acro signed pdf](http://ubuntuone.com/7Qq9G75js7zkPvh07YqisR) (same cert, same tsa server)

Comment: Please provide a sample PDF signed and time stamped using your code; BTW, iText 2.1.7 and BC 1.49 looks like a funny combination, given that that old iText version in its own code relies on BC versions from before the big BC API break 1.46/1.47. Ah, there is one issue visible in your code; I'll create an answer...

Comment: My assumption that I had spotted an *issue visible in your code* proved wrong after I looked at the specification.

Comment: mkl, I forgot to mention tha I made some changes in iText source code to make it compatible with BC 1.49. AFAIK that changes are not responsible of my problem, with that same code I succesfully sign several documents in differents formats (xml, doc, etc.)

Comment: I've started to look into your samples at office but i didn't have enough time. It was weird, though. .. having extracted the cms containers,  dumpasn1 ran into a runtime error when trying to open your container and also showed multiple errors for the one generated By Adobe. Furthermore Adobe's signature was gigantic!

Comment: Ok, with a newer guidumpasn version I can properly parse both CMS comtainers. At first glance they look ok. The main difference being that Adobe embeds a huge CRL and so makes the PDF size explode. A major difference remaining is that you are creating an **ETSI.CAdES.detached** signature while Adobe creates an old-fashioned **adbe.pkcs7.detached**. Have you tried first going for a **adbe.pkcs7.detached** signature, too? The Reader may have different validations for these different types. And: You do include a signing-time attribute which is forbidden for **ETSI.CAdES.detached**. Try without.

Comment: I see no differences between ETSI.CAdES.detached and adbe.pkcs7.detached (from A.Reader point of view), as well as with or without signing-time property. A.Reader messages are the same for all cases.

Comment: The only other difference I see is that you have added your user certificate twice to the certificates collection of the CMS container. It would be quite a surprise if that caused time stamp related issues. I have not checked whether the time stamp stamps the correct hash yet, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Instead of timestamping the hash of CMSAttributeTableGenerator.SIGNATURE (it is known while signing with BC using CMSAttributeTableGenerator), I was timestamping the hash of the resolved signature (CMSSignedData.getEncoded()). Maybe, my next goal would be to get the correct data outside of CMSAttributeTableGenerator, I tested saving that and timestamping after signing, and putting the timestamp into the SignerInformationStore (using the source code that I wrote above) and the Reader's validation gets correct. I hope you understand what I meant to say (this is not my native language). Thank you all.

Comment: Great you got it. Unfortunately you had not posted that part of the code to begin with, otherwise the issue might have been identified earlier. That been said, you should also work on the minor issues identified in the comments above (signing-time attribute conflicting with **ETSI.CAdES.detached**, duplicate certificate entries...).

Comment: You are right mkl. If I had have a clue about the issue I would posted the code, but my suspicious were totally misguided. Btw, I already remove the signing-time attribute and the duplicated certificate for PAdES-T. Thank you very much.